# tcolorbox options in nested style fail to work

Tags: tcolorbox

Please see the picture and code for my question.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

    \begin{document}

    % define a new style named selfsetcontainer by container/.code
    \tcbset{container/.code={\tcbset{selfsetcontainer/.style={#1}}},
      container/.default={}}

    \begin{tcolorbox}[container,colback=yellow,selfsetcontainer={colback=green}]
      I want green background color, but get yellow. That is to say, the option 'colback=green' in nested style does not work. Why and how to solve it?
    \end{tcolorbox}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you got some things mixed up. You need to pass the option to the code, not to the style. In the code, you define the style. So how would the code know that you want to define a green style? This will only work if you tell this to the code, i.e. pass the argument to it. (And I think it is somewhat advantageous to use `\pgfkeysalso` here simply because that decreases the chances of you getting trapped in a loop or other dismay.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

    % define a new style named selfsetcontainer by container/.code
    \tcbset{container/.code={\pgfkeysalso{selfsetcontainer/.style={#1}}},
      container/.default={}}

    \begin{tcolorbox}[container={colback=green},colback=yellow,selfsetcontainer]
      I want green background color, and that's what I get. I set the style in
      the \texttt{container} code, where I have decided to switch to
      \verb|\pgfkeysalso| in order to reduce the chances of confusing
      Ti\emph{k}Z, which underlies the \texttt{tcolorbox} package.
    \end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Response to your comment**: Yes, one can define a code that defines a possibly empty style. However, in order to set the style, you need to call another code. This leads to

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

    % define a new style named selfsetcontainer by container/.code
    \tcbset{container/.code={\tcbset{selfsetcontainer/.style={#1}}},
      container/.default={},
      set style/.code n args={2}{\pgfkeysalso{#1/.style={#2}}}}

    \begin{tcolorbox}[container,colback=yellow,set
    style={selfsetcontainer}{colback=green},selfsetcontainer]
      This is a rather involved way of accomplishing the same:
      \begin{enumerate}
       \item \texttt{container} is a code that defines an empty style named 
       \texttt{selfsetcontainer}.
       \item \texttt{set style} is another code that sets the style of
       container, or more generally, of any style.
       \item Finally, \texttt{container} is now a style that makes the
       background green.
      \end{enumerate}
    \end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that the last two steps may be combined to one (at the expense of having a more complicated construction). Are you *sure* you want to go that way?

Comment: Perfect and simplie solution!! I have a look at \pgfkeysalso in pgf manuel, but don't understand its use in this example of mine, could you please say more about it and why nested \tcbset is a wrong way?

Comment: @lyl I added a more complicated solution. Why `\pgfkeysalso`? Are you content with the information that whenever I got some really cool piece code by very advanced users like Jake or percusse, they tend to use that trick. It might be that the only reason is that you do not have to worry about the path, i.e. you could copy the above 1-to-1 to Ti*k*Z (of course not the `colback` part, but the principle).

Comment: Many thanks!! The vesion one you  provide is simple and perfect, the veseon two gives me more helpfule info!

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity Please stop making such comments. The color was not chosen by me, nor has it any importance here. The only thing that matters here is that the color gets changed in the way the OP wanted it to change.